# Use substitution in Sphinx with MyST

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext, myst

[MyST](https://github.com/executablebooks/myst-parser) allows to write sphinx documentation in markdown.
Is it possible to combine it with substitutions?

Comment: The best way is to open an issue to MyST developers.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible.

First, you need to enable the `substitution` extension in your `conf.py` file:

```
# Don't forget to activate `myst_parser` as well
extensions = [
    # ...
    'myst_parser'
]
myst_enable_extensions = [
    # ...
    'substitution'
]
```

Still in your `conf.py` file, you have to define your substitutions in the `myst_substitutions` dictionary.

```
myst_substitutions = {
    'my_name': 'Luiz Oliveira'
}
```

Finally, in your markdown file, you can use substitutions by passing their key inside double curly brackets (`{{YOUR_SUB_KEY}}`) like this:

```
<!-- This is my markdown file -->
This document was written by {{my_name}}.
```

Which would generate the output:

> This document was written by Luiz Oliveira.